# Why are these divs different sizes when the CSS are the same?

Tags: css, html, css-float, height, element

I have a div (.soundLogoContainer") and an aside (".iAmSam") inside a main. The 2 child elements share very similar CSS, the only difference WAS that one was float left and the other was float right. Now I am using inline-block.

However, according to Dreamweaver and my browsers, the .soundLogoContainer div and the .iAmSam aside are offset still. I want the grey div to be at top 0 relatively (the same way as the yellow div sits under the header with no gap).

I do not understand why this happening and wish to fix it.

Any help, I will be very thankful.

```
       <main>

  <aside class="iAmSam columnDiv">
    <p>aside iAmSam columnDiv</p>
  </aside>

  <div class="soundLogoContainer columnDiv">
    <p>div "soundLogoContainer columnDiv </p>
  </div>

  <div class="homeSkillContainer">div</div>

</main>

    body main {
    background-color: skyblue;
}

.columnDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
}

.soundLogoContainer {
    background-color: grey;
}


.iAmSam {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image: the 2 child elements (div and aside) are still offset]

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property `height` are different. One has 150px, another one has 200px.

Also, the inner content `<img>` changes the outer element size. Try to remove the `<img>` and check that both have the same size.

To be more helpful, you can add multiple classes to same element. Try create a class with the shared properties:

```
<main>
  <aside class="box iAmSam">aside<img class="imgtextIMAKE" src="../assets/Text/iamsam.svg" alt="I am Sam"/></aside>

  <div class="box soundLogoContainer">div</div>
  <div class="homeSkillContainer">div</div>
</main>

.soundLogoContainer {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}

.iAmSam {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: yes, this works better, However, I still have an offset for some reason.

Comment: i have also noticed that if I remove/delet the .iAmSam div (the yellow right div) then .soundLogoContainer (grey div)  is NOT pushed down and sits flush with the div above (pink)

Comment: It happens because your ```<main>``` have a fixed height: 400px. If you remove it height rule, it goes up, but due to your float rule, the element would be undocked.

Try this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/cqx09mam

The problem is a set of rules: float, position, display... Too complex to explain.

Comment: I see that your fiddle works, exactly how I want it to. However, it still doesn't seem to work. What am I missing? Thanks again.

Comment: @SamBegdouri, you should create your own fiddle for that. I tried to help you, but I cannot see your real code. Please, share it.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/3hjozs1g
I used ```display:inline-table``` instead ```inline-block```, added it to ```.main``` and ```.columnDiv``` and also added ```width:100%``` to ```.main```.
Please, check that you were using a lot of positions ```absolute``` and ```relative```, even ```float:left```. Be careful changing the style with these properties.

Comment: Firstly, a massive thanks for all this. One last thing. You have made a fix, which is more than I could have thought of. However, it still breaks at 352px. I don't want it to break until 320px for small screen sizes such as the earlier iphones 3-5